# Selenium MoveToElement Action is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

On performing MoveToElement Action,Mouse hasnt moved to the element location.Please find the below code.

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.MoveToElement(element);
    action.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Please see the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section about asking a question and providing more and more details for you to be helped by the community.

Comment: @sowmya Can you consider to update the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Comment: The code you have put into your question isn't designed to move the mouse to the element location, all this will so is scroll the page until the target element is in view. If you provided more context around what you are trying to do, you may be able to get a better answer on how to accomplish it.

Comment: @Jsmith2800,
So which selenium action is used for mouse movement??

Answer (score -3):

You can try the below code:

```
 IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Login_Id"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.MoveToElement(element);
        action.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Instead of just giving the code, it would be good if you can explain why the OP's question is having issues and how your code's gonna fix it.